# Obtain the file I "grep" with find + cat

Tags: string, bash, grep

I am trying to get the file name where the grepped text belongs.

I use this:

```
find . -type f -name "*py" -exec cat -n {} \; | grep -H login.html
```

and I obtain this:

```
(standard input):    11     url(r'^login$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='dojo/login.html', authentication_form=AuthenticationForm), name='login'),
```

Usually I use the option `-a` with cat also, when I get "standard input" log, but here, since I "cat" every file, I am not sure how to proceed.

Regards.

Comment: Why don't you -exec `grep -H pattern {}` directly instead of `cat`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this entirely with Grep

```
grep -R -H --include="*.py" login.html
```

-R = Rescursion

-H = Add filenames

--include= Glob for file (similar to your -name of find)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using xargs:
`find . -type f -name "*py"  | xargs grep -H login.html`. You might need to use `-print0` option in `find` and `-0` in `xargs` if your file names contain spaces.
What xargs does is to pass output of the previous command (basically its own stdin) as command arguments to its argument